# Lua and Love2D, table in table error

Tags: lua, love2d

Why isn't this working? I'm trying to put all my object tables in a single table and use a forloop to iterate through each of them and draw. It shows an error message saying: "}" expected near "=" at line 5

```
function love.load()
solidstatic = {
ground = {x = 0,y = 160,width = 1000,height = 1000},
box = {x = 80,y = 100,width = 15,height = 15}
}

end


function love.draw()
for i,obj in ipairs(solidstatic) do
love.graphics.rectangle("fill",obj[x],obj[y],obj[width],obj[height])
end
end
```

(edit) solved the error problem, I was running the wrong .lua file. But still, it doesn't draw anything on the screen

Comment: The `solidstatic` table has no array keys so `ipairs` doesn't iterate over anything.

Answer (score 1):

Two things.
Firstly, you must use pairs instead of ipairs to list keys that are not numbers.

```
for i, v in pairs(table) do
    ...
end
```

You must also index the variables as a string.

```
t = {
    x = 1
}

t['x'] = 1
-- or
t.x = 1
```

This is because doing it without quotes would be indexing with the global variable x, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `pairs` instead of `ipairs` to iterate over elements in `solidstatic` as there are no array keys in that table.